# Gas Pipe Sizing

Tags: natural-gas

I recently got a quote to have a gas system installed. The outside stuff will be done by the utility company, they are putting in a 2 psi system.

My plumber is going to run 3/4 hard pipe to my utility room, t with a drip leg, line regulator, and then manifold to serve a dryer, water heater and cooktop.

He said with the 2 psi system it allows for the use of smaller diameter piping running to the appliances. I just wanted to clarify the correct pipe sizing. With the line regulator reducing the pressure, wouldn’t you size the pipes according to the pressure after the regulator and not size the piping based on the 2 psi before the regulator?

Comment: You might ask what would be needed for an on-demand water heater. Installing ours required an up-size to the pipe (to 1" I believe) which was not part of the original estimate (but Costco ate the difference).

Comment: To what PSI does the line regulator reduce? What's the linear foot pipe distance to each appliance? Typically, a stove can take up to 70k btu, 30k dryer, and 40k for a water heater.

Comment: So I’m really just curious which chart you use for sizing pipe after the regulator, the 2 psi chart or the 1/4 psi chart, which is what the regulator would reduce the pressure to. 

The set up would be 3/4” pipe 15 ft from meter to manifold at 2 psi (according to the chart this can handle 1000k btu. 

5 ft to 199k water heater, 10ft to 20k dryer, 15 feet to 50k btu cooktop

Comment: If a line is at 0.25 psi, then surely that line must be sized by the 0.25 psi chart. What is the location of the step-down regulator from 2 psi to 0.25 psi? Is it just outside the structure?

Comment: Yes, size the pipe for after the pressure drop. Some plumbers falsely size piping based on an assumption that you will not be using all appliances at 100% power at once. This saves you money in material but it's pennies compared to the labor cost which would be the same regardless of pipe size. Size it for maximum usage and add 1/4 inch for future expansion.

Comment: Okay that’s what I was thinking. The step down from 2psi to .25 will be in my mechanical room. Line from street to regulator at meter which is 2psi, 2 psi running through main line to mechanical room to a line regulator which steps it down to .25 psi, into a manifold and then csst from manifold to each appliance.